# How to write a clone method easily?

Tags: c++

I have a base class with a virtual clone new method

```
class A
{
    virtual A* cloneNew() const { return new A; }
};
```

and its derivatives

```
class A1 : public A
{
    virtual A1* cloneNew() const { return new A1; }
};

class A2 : public A
{
    virtual A2* cloneNew() const { return new A2; }
};
```

Now I want to use macro or other way to make its re-implementation more easily like

```
class A1: public A
{
    CLONE_NEW; // no type A1 here
};
```

Is it possible to do it? Does decltype(this) help?

Comment: Having a clone method is usually an indication of something wrong in the design (code smell). What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @Loki Astari Can you elaborate on why a clone method is code smell?

Comment: @LokiAstari I have dynamically-typed items in a tree of a GUI. I want to create a new similar item when an item is clicked.

Comment: It's not very C++ like (hence the code smell). Looks like something I would do in Java. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6626201/14065

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works fine for me, and can easily be turned into a macro:

```
struct Foo
{
    virtual auto clone() -> decltype(this)
    {
        return new auto(*this);
    }
};
```

If you want the `clone()` function to be `const`, you cannot use `new auto` and you have to work a bit harder with the return type:

```
#include <type_traits>

virtual auto clone() const -> std::decay<decltype(*this)>::type *
{
    return new std::decay<decltype(*this)>::type(*this);
}
```

Comment: @user1899020 MSVC11 (The C++ compiler of VS2012) [does not support C++11 completely](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx). On the other hand, as far I know MSVC11 supports trailing return type and the `decltype` specifier, so the problem should be at the implementation of `std::decay`. Whats exactly your compiler error?

Comment: MSVC11 shows `this` can only be used in the internal body of non-static methods of a class. The problem is on  `-> decltype(this)`

Comment: @user1899020 I have tried that in my VS2012 installation and fails too. Seems like a MSVC11 bug.