# Looking for a design pattern to apply in C++

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have these C++ classes defined as follows:

```c
class A
{
public:
    B *createB();
};

class B 
{
public:
    virtual void fun() = 0;
};
class B1 : B {/* ... */};
class B2 : B {/* ... */};
```

So basically B is an abstract class, B1 and B2 are concrete implementations of B, and A creates an instance of type B somewhere in its code. It's important to note that **A is not a factory**, `A::createB` is just an example.

I'd like to be able to pass a subclass of B during initialization of A so it is possible to create instances of the former by the latter as necessary during runtime. Example:

```
A *a1 = /* sorcery here */;
A *a2 = /* another magic code */;

a1->createB(); // getting B1
a2->createB(); // getting B2
```

What is the best way to achieve it? Is it possible **without** using templates?

---

Basing on responses I ended up with this. Thanks!

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual void fun() = 0;
    virtual B *clone() = 0;
};

class B1 : public B
{
public:
    virtual void fun()
    {
        std::cout << "B1" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual B *clone()
    {
        return new B1();
    }
};

class B2 : public B {/* analogous to B1 */};

class A
{
public:
    A(B *b) : b(b) {};

    B *createB()
    {
        return b->clone();
    }
private:
    B *b;
};

A(new B1()).createB()->fun(); // prints "B1"
A(new B2()).createB()->fun(); // prints "B2"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement a `clone()` method in B.

Pass a `B*` to A when creating it. A will call B's `clone()` with that `B*` as a parameter.

For further information about cloning see questions [Which situation will use clone in C++ and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7708110/96780), [What's the best signature for clone() in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/259853/96780) and [How to write a clone method easily?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19607609/96780), among others.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [*Prototype*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) design pattern to achieve this. Pass `A` an instance of `B1` or `B2`, and add a `clone()` member function to `B`, like this:

```
class B 
{
public:
    virtual void fun() = 0;
    virtual B* clone() = 0; // B1::clone returns new B1; B2::clone returns new B2
};
```

`A` stores the prototype instance of `B` passed in during initialization for later use. When it needs to create a new `B` later on, it calls `clone()` on the prototype to get an instance of the right class.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [abstract factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

You can see example [here](https://gist.github.com/pazdera/1102546) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Window
{
protected:
int width;
int height;
std::string toolkit;
std::string type;

Window(std::string usedToolkit, std::string windowType)
: toolkit(usedToolkit), type(windowType)
{}

public:
std::string getToolkit()
{
return toolkit;
}

std::string getType()
{
return type;
}
};

class GtkToolboxWindow : public Window
{
public:
GtkToolboxWindow()
: Window("Gtk", "ToolboxWindow")
{}
};

class GtkLayersWindow : public Window
{
public:
GtkLayersWindow()
: Window("Gtk", "LayersWindow")
{}
};

class GtkMainWindow : public Window
{
public:
GtkMainWindow()
: Window("Gtk", "MainWindow")
{}
};


class QtToolboxWindow : public Window
{
public:
QtToolboxWindow()
: Window("Qt", "ToolboxWindow")
{}
};

class QtLayersWindow : public Window
{
public:
QtLayersWindow()
: Window("Qt", "LayersWindow")
{}
};

class QtMainWindow : public Window
{
public:
QtMainWindow()
: Window("Qt", "MainWindow")
{}
};


/* This is the abstract factory. */
class UIFactory
{
public:
virtual Window* getToolboxWindow() = 0;
virtual Window* getLayersWindow() = 0;
virtual Window* getMainWindow() = 0;

};

/* Factory for Gtk toolkit */
class GtkUIFactory : public UIFactory
{
public:
Window* getToolboxWindow()
{
return new GtkToolboxWindow();
}

Window* getLayersWindow()
{
return new GtkLayersWindow();
}

Window* getMainWindow()
{
return new GtkMainWindow();
}
};

/* Factory for Qt toolkit */
class QtUIFactory : public UIFactory
{
public:
Window* getToolboxWindow()
{
return new QtToolboxWindow();
}

Window* getLayersWindow()
{
return new QtLayersWindow();
}

Window* getMainWindow()
{
return new QtMainWindow();
}
};

int main()
{
UIFactory* ui = 0;

/* Check what environment is running
and create appropriate factory. */
if (/* Gtk == */ true)
{
ui = new GtkUIFactory();
}
else
{
ui = new QtUIFactory();
}

/* Use the factory to build interface. */
Window* toolbox = ui->getToolboxWindow();
Window* layers = ui->getLayersWindow();
Window* main = ui->getMainWindow();

/* See what have we recieved. */
std::cout << toolbox->getToolkit() << ":"
<< toolbox->getType() << std::endl;

std::cout << layers->getToolkit() << ":"
<< layers->getType() << std::endl;

std::cout << main->getToolkit() << ":"
<< main->getType() << std::endl;
}
```